# Writing HTML code in Javascript inside a PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

I need to write in PHP, inside a Javascript portion code, an hidden input tag with an javascript array that I need to pass to another PHP code ..

This is the sample code ...

```
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

    <other javascript code .... >

    echo 'arr_selections_json = JSON.stringify(arr_selections);';
    echo 'document.write("<input type="hidden" name="arr_selections_json" value="+arr_selections_json+" />")';
```

This code doesn't work .... Any suggestions? 
Thank you in advance .. .

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: also, there isn't a closing script tag

Comment: Escape your JavaScript quotes

Comment: @jaysingkar. Sorrry ... the error in my Chrome console is ... "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @jaysingkar... which tag??

Comment: @Cesare look at Unex's answer, that would be the best way to achieve this

Comment: if you face any issue, let us know

Answer (score 0):

You need to JS-escape the double quotes inside the argument of document.write() 
e.g.

```
echo 'document.write("<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"arr_selections_json" value=\\"" + arr_selections_json + "\\" />")';
```

Also, I've had recent weird cases, where document.write wouldn't consider the closing slash (/>), whereas it's HTML-5 compliant. I had to escape with a backslash the closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">;
<other javascript code .... >

    arr_selections_json = <?php echo JSON.stringify(arr_selections); ?>;
    document.write('<input type="hidden" name="+arr_selections_json+" value="+arr_selections_json+" />');
</script>
```

I'm not sure what are your php part, but i think you should be ok like this.